# Office 365 REST API - Adding a Contact with JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, post, office365

I am trying to use the Office API to sync contacts from a few different sources. I have been having a problem trying to make a POST request with my JSON object to create a new contact. I have been looking at the MSDN pages but I feel like I should clarify I’m relatively new to C#, this is my first time trying to use REST protocols, and async methods in C#.

I have my code below, I tried to create a class that will add a new contact with a hard coded JSON string. I have tried a few various ways of trying to complete this request. Every request I have attempted gives me a 401 or 400 Error. I left a couple lines that I felt were closest to the solution but if those are not on the right track I have no problem trying something else. There is also a function that I believe could be useful but I couldn’t really find documentation on how to use it:

```
await client.Me.Contacts.AddContactAsync();
```

Again I said I am pretty new to this so if there is a way to create an IContact item from the JSON and use the above method or to just pass the JSON directly either would be extremely useful. Even links to documentation that could be useful I would love to see. I’m a pretty stuck on this problem I’ve never posted a question before but I’m stumped on this.

Below is the documentation for the Contacts API maybe it will make more sense to you guys than me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn792115(v=office.15).aspx

If anybody can figure out how to make a post request from that JSON it will be much appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Office365.Exchange;
using Microsoft.Office365.OAuth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ContactSynchronization
{
    class OfficeAPIWrite
    {
        private static string odata = "@odata.type";
        private static string type = "#Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact";


        const string ServiceResourceId = "https://outlook.office365.com";
        static readonly Uri ServiceEndpointUri = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts");

        static string _lastLoggedInUser;
        static DiscoveryContext _discoveryContext;

        public static async Task OfficeWrite()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = await EnsureClientCreated();

                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    odata = type,
                    GivenName = "Mara",
                    Surname = "Whitley",
                    EmailAddress1 = "mara@fabrikam.com",
                    BusinessPhone1 = "425-555-1313",
                    Birthday = "1974-07-22T07:00:00Z"
                });

                try
                {
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ServiceEndpointUri);
                    request.Content = new StringContent(json);
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Microsoft.Office365.OAuth.AuthenticationFailedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Authentication Failed Exception was thrown");
            }
        }

        public static async Task<ExchangeClient> EnsureClientCreated()
        {
            if (_discoveryContext == null)
            {
                _discoveryContext = await DiscoveryContext.CreateAsync();
            }

            var dcr = await _discoveryContext.DiscoverResourceAsync(ServiceResourceId);

            _lastLoggedInUser = dcr.UserId;

            return new ExchangeClient(ServiceEndpointUri, async () =>
            {
                return (await _discoveryContext.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ServiceResourceId, _discoveryContext.AppIdentity.ClientId, new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier(dcr.UserId, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType.UniqueId))).AccessToken;
            });
        }

        public static async Task SignOut()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastLoggedInUser))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_discoveryContext == null)
            {
                _discoveryContext = await DiscoveryContext.CreateAsync();
            }

            await _discoveryContext.LogoutAsync(_lastLoggedInUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess I figured out a work around. This uses a ContactObject that I created and newtonsoft's JSON serializer. I was hoping to see an example of the microsoft ExchangeClient in action, the only reason I am posting this is to help others that might have similar issues posting to the office API, the below code will run successfully. I'm still looking though if anybody can show me the correct way to use the ExchangeClient functions.

```
    // your request must include these, and a given name,
    // everything else is optional
    private const string odata = "@odata.type";
    private const string type = "#Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact";

    public static async Task CreateContact(ContactObject officeContact, string userEmail, string userPassword)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts"));

        // Add the Authorization header with the basic login credentials.
        var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userEmail + ":" + userPassword));
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

        var createResponse = new JObject();
        createResponse[odata] = type; // this needs to be here for this to work
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeDisplayName)) createResponse["DisplayName"] = officeContact.officeDisplayName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeGivenName)) createResponse["GivenName"] = officeContact.officeGivenName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeMiddleName)) createResponse["MiddleName"] = officeContact.officeMiddleName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeNickName)) createResponse["NickName"] = officeContact.officeNickName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeSurname)) createResponse["Surname"] = officeContact.officeSurname;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeEmailAddress1)) createResponse["EmailAddress1"] = officeContact.officeEmailAddress1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeEmailAddress2)) createResponse["EmailAddress2"] = officeContact.officeEmailAddress2;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeEmailAddress3)) createResponse["EmailAddress3"] = officeContact.officeEmailAddress3;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeHomePhone1)) createResponse["HomePhone1"] = officeContact.officeHomePhone1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeHomePhone2)) createResponse["HomePhone2"] = officeContact.officeHomePhone2;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeBusinessPhone1)) createResponse["BusinessPhone1"] = officeContact.officeBusinessPhone1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeBusinessPhone2)) createResponse["BusinessPhone2"] = officeContact.officeBusinessPhone2;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeMobilePhone1)) createResponse["MobilePhone1"] = officeContact.officeMobilePhone1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeOtherPhone)) createResponse["OtherPhone"] = officeContact.officeOtherPhone;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeId)) createResponse["Id"] = officeContact.officeId;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officeContact.officeCompanyName)) createResponse["CompanyName"] = officeContact.officeCompanyName;

        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createResponse));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BAD REQUEST");
        }
    }
```